# Are there any archaic features in this passage

Tags: ancien-français

This speech is spoken by Bloch in Proust.  It was translated into English using a few archaisms.  Are there are any French Archaisms in it, that is expressions that would have been archaic in 1913.  'Par Apollon' I wouldn't consider to be archaic rather just eccentric.

Also, has the word 'coco' died out in modern french in the sense of 'disreputable person'?  The dictonary defines the [word](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coco/2) as:

> Triste individu, personnage peu recommandable

And here I think 'triste' probably means 'unfortunate' in English rather than the usual translation which is 'sad'.  Actually I forgot [this site](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/coco) counts how often a word is translated into English and more than 10K times it is translated into 'coconut' and only about 20 times is it translated into 'dude','bloke' or 'chic', so I think it's safe to say that it is no longer used in that sense, correct me if I'm wrong.

> Défie-toi de ta dilection assez basse pour le sieur de Musset. C’est un coco des plus malfaisants et une assez sinistre brute. Je dois confesser, d’ailleurs, que lui et même le nommé Racine, ont fait chacun dans leur vie un vers assez bien rythmé, et qui a pour lui, ce qui est selon moi le mérite suprême, de ne signifier absolument rien. C’est : « La blanche Oloossone et la blanche Camire » et « La fille de Minos et de Pasiphaé». Ils m’ont été signalés à la décharge de ces deux malandrins par un article de mon très cher maître, le père Lecomte, agréable aux Dieux immortels. À propos voici un livre que je n’ai pas le temps de lire en ce moment qui est recommandé, paraît-il, par cet immense bonhomme. Il tient, m’a-t-on dit, l’auteur, le sieur Bergotte, pour un coco des plus subtils , et bien qu’il fasse preuve, des fois, de mansuétudes assez mal explicables, sa parole est pour moi oracle delphique. Lis donc ces proses lyriques, et si le gigantesque assembleur de rythmes qui a écrit Bhagavat et le Levrier de Magnus a dit vrai, par Apollon tu goûteras, cher maître, les joies nectaréennes de l’Olympos.

Comment: Attends on ne fait pas d'analyse de texte sans questions plus précises.  Tu peux préciser la question, un vers par exemple ? Bon *triste* veut dire les deux, c'est comme ça la traduction.

Comment: I don't see how I can be any more precise then: 'are there are archaic features in this text,' what is about the question that you don't understand?

Comment: Instead of asking for yes or no, please ask about or point out what sounds archaic to you and what you don't understand.  Is it the verb tenses?  The vocabulary? Something else?

Comment: None of it appears archaic to me, that's why I'm asking why it was translated into English with archaic features.  If I could spot the archaic features, obviously I would not have posted the question.

Comment: Parsing is not allowed, as says user livresque. Here is something about that, but I don't know for sure: "immense" might not be used nowadays as Proust used it (− En partic. au xixe s. [En parlant d'un homme] Dont la personnalité, les capacités intellectuelles sont très grandes.) https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/immense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer about the word "coco".

Modern use of "coco" is to be assimilated rather to that proposed by the Wiktionnary, although not fully; the usage recorded in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coco/2) might be rare nowadays; this is shown by [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/coco) ("Un coco est sorti en courant…"). The Wiktionary mentions only "address sharply" (interpellation), but yet gives examples which do not fit into this category (in particular, the Proust example). Also, very often, the addressing is not real but of a simulated sort, when the person so addressed is not present (pseudo-addressing, we might say). Also, the meaning is not "disreputable"; this can be seen in particular from the second example below; it is used so as to express disdain  with varying degrees of intensity, disdain which can be quite mild at times or to express, as well the amusement derived from a position of superiority over the persons so adressed because their behaviour is thought to be naive, innocently rash, improper in a more or less unconscious way, etc.

It seems anyway that the sense as in Proust is ambiguous; there are two cases of use in the same paragraph, and the second does not mean "disreputable person", clearly. Perhaps both cases are to be rekoned with as meaning merely "guy".

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/coco)) (Péjoratif) (Familier) Interpellation péjorative ou méprisante. — Note : En général précédé par « mon » ou « ma », ou au pluriel « mes ».
>
> • Angèle. — Hein ? Robineau ?… Ah ! bien ! Parlons-en, de lui ! **C’est un joli coco** ! — (Georges Feydeau, Le Système Ribadier, 1892, acte I, scène 8)
> • Bref, me voilà en route avec mes huit grosses valises, mes cinq tubars, le banquier Chauvassut, le noceur Clergerie, l’industriel Montagnoux, le poète Bois-Méard et le petit jeune homme de bonne famille, Gabriel Duplessis-Tournel. J’aurais très bien vu **ces cinq cocos-là** en uniforme bleu horizon avec un flingue baïonnette au canon, là bas, à Craonne, avec les copains. — (Pierre Siniac, L’Unijambiste de la cote 284)
> • Défie-toi de ta dilection assez basse pour le sieur de Musset. **C’est un coco** des plus malfaisants et une assez sinistre brute. — (Marcel Proust, À la recherche du temps perdu, Du côté de chez Swann, 1913, Éditions Gallimard, Folio n°1924, 1987, page 89)
> • Toi, **mon coco**, tu vas passer un sale quart d’heure !
> • Vous ne perdez rien pour attendre, **mes cocos** !

Comment: very helpful, as always LPH

Answer (score 1):

*Dilection* was already very rare (I had to look it up in a dictionary). *Sieur* is definitely archaic.

Comment: thanks, i appreciate that